# how to test facebook app for different scenarios

Tags: facebook

how to test a facebook app for different use cases. i will take a simple example here:

assuming i have a facebook app which just does the login to a site.

now, how do i handle/ test different use cases in this:
1) user is already connected to the site and logging in again using her facebook account
2) user is a first time user and want to login to my site through his facebook credential and she a) allows the app to access her details b) deny the app to access her details

these are the very basic test cases but there could be more depending upon what exactly what we want to do with that app and the site.

so my question is how does one test all these scenarios ? if i use my facebook account once then it doesn't allow me to test the other scenario (like if i once allow an app then it doesn't allow me to test the 'deny' scenario)

thanks in advance

dev

Answer (score 1):

> You can use [test users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/) for manual or automated testing.